# How do I use JAVA programs on Mac that were originally created on PC

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

so I've ran into a small problem and I'm hoping someone can help me.

At home and at school (when I can get on to a computer at school) I normally use Netbeans on a PC, which isn't a problem. I load netbeans and open my projects which I have saved on an external HDD.

If I am on the go, or at a location in school that doesn't have a PC I use my MAC, unfortunately when I load netbeans I am unable to open saved projects from my external HDD.

Is this a comparability issue? I was always under the impression netbeans could load and run any program regardless of the OS as long as you were using the same netbeans platform. Nevertheless, I am unable to open my PC netbeans projects on my MAC and I was hoping someone could tell me what I needed to do to convert these files. As I frequently alternate been PC and MAC to work on my projects.

Thank You

Comment: Do you get any error message, when Netbeans fails to open the project?

Comment: Looks like an issue on how the property files for the Netbeans project were saved. I would recommend saving your data in a repository using git/mercurial in sites like github or bitbucket. After that, clone the repository in whatever OS you work with. Also, use a project management tool like maven or ivy, this way your project structure won't be tied to an specific IDE and/or its specific details.

Comment: I use github for saving and sharing my code between systems.  We have development PCs which are Windows, Mac and Ubuntu + Centos and these are shared without a problem.

Comment: Ah I see, I never heard about github until now. Since my programs alternate between PC and MAC I'll try this github and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Is it the same version of Netbeans eg. are you trying to open projects created with Netbeans 8.0 on the PC with version 7.x on the MAC. If so, upgrade. Did you copy the entire directory from the PC to the external HDD including the nbproject sub-directory and all its sub-directories? If not go back to the PC and make sure you copy everything.

Comment: Both are running 8.0.2 and yes ALL files have been copied. For some reason I can't open my HDD when using the MAC version of NetBeans. Normally I go to file open project, but on MAC I can't, so alternatively I just copy the files from the HDD to my MAC and attempt to open that way. I'm thinking about reinstalling netbeans on both PC and MAC again to see if that resolves the issue.